# Is there a way to listen to angular events like routechangestart from outside, like from browser console or an add on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension, angular-ui-router, dom-events

I want to listen to `routechangestart` event of my application from browser console or inside a browser extension. Is there a way to do this?
I haven't tried anything yet because I have little knowledge about how Angular works.
I want this to notify the user whenever a view is changed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you want some code to be executed from console at state change events, you could use something like:

```
angular.element(document).scope().   $on("$stateChangeStart",function(){//your code here
}
```

Just change the event name from `$stateChangeStart` to whatever event you want to listen to

Comment: Thanks @dilip. Precisely what I was looking for.